# Maximize the amount of covered demand

Tags: optimization, mathematical-modeling, binary, operations-research, mixed-integer-programming

> Let's assume there is a demand node with demand $D$ which this demand should be covered within a 24 hours window. The objective is to find the best delivery times to maximize the amount of covered demand volume within a time window $T$ where $T$ can be defined as follows: 
>   $$
> T \in \{ [t_1,t_2],[t_3,t_4]\} 
> $$
>   where $t_k$ denote a time of a day (e.g., $t_1$ is 10 AM).
>   We have following constraints:
>
> 1. $2 \le t_2-t_1 \le 5$
> 2. $2 \le t_4-t_3 \le 5$
> 3. $t_3-t_2 \ge 1$
> 4. $t_2-t_1+t_4-t_3 \le 8$
>
> (1) and (2) make sure that each time range length should be minimum 2 hours and maximum 5 hours and also (3) indicates that at least one hour gap should be established between the two ranges, and finally (4) makes sure that the length of the two ranges won't exceed 8 hours. There is also a constraint with respect to delivery rate which limits max delivery throughput within each hour to be a constant value $U \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

I was thinking to approach this problem as a Maximum coverage problem and generate all possible time ranges and set set each generated time range as a binary decision variable e.g.,$x_1$ is to cover within [5AM,9AM] and $y_1$ is the amount that is covered within this time range, but not sure if this is the best approach to formulate this problem.

Thanks in advance for any insights.

Comment: I think constraint 4 should look like $t_2 - t_1 + t_4-t_3 \le 8$

Comment: Thanks  @ErwinKalvelagen. You are right.

Comment: This problem is a bit like employee scheduling. There are quite a few approaches. See [link](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/01/employee-scheduling-i-matlab-vs-gams.html) (and subsequent posts) for some examples using the same data set.

Comment: Is the time window $T$ fixed (input), or is that what the model is trying to decide? Are there multiple demand nodes and you are trying to decide what order to visit them in?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 T  is that what the model is trying to decide. There is only one demand node and the model tries to decide the optimal visit times given the set of abovementioned constraints. The objective is st maximize the coverage of the node's demand.

Comment: So in other words, you want to decide $T$ *and* $t_1,\ldots,t_4$ so that the total length of the intervals $[t_1,t_2] + [t_3,t_4]$ is as large as possible, subject to the constraints -- is that right?

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 That is true.

Comment: Then why not just formulate it as an LP with objective function $\text{max} (t_2-t_1) + (t_4-t_3)$ subject to those constraints? I think that will be easier than trying to shoehorn the problem into another problem like max cover.